# Call a method with String[] parameter using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, parameters

I have used all the suggestions I could find on StackOverflow and other sites for this. I am trying to invoke a method using reflection. Here is the code for my method:

```
public void my_method(String[] args) {

    for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(args);
    }
}
```

Here is the code I used for reflection

```
Class[] paramStringArray = new Class[1];    
paramStringArray[0] = String[].class;
String[] argu = {"hey", "there"};

Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("my_method", paramStringArray);
method.invoke(obj, new Object[]{argu});
```

My issue is that when I run the program, I see the output printed as: [Ljava.lang.String;@70a6aa31
[Ljava.lang.String;@70a6aa31

I have tried all the suggestions I could find. Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: `Object#toString()` is your keyword. Why are you trying the advanced topic of reflection when you don't yet know how to print an object? Slow down.

Comment: `args` is a `String[]`. It does not have a custom `toString()` method to print its contents. Use `Arrays.toString(args);` to return a String with the contents of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `my_method()` receives as a parameter a `String[]`, not a `String`. You're calling a different method. The code should look like this:

```
paramString[0] = String[].class;
Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("my_method", paramString);
```

To invoke it, pass a `String[]` as parameter:

```
method.invoke(obj, new String[]{"x"});
```

Also, the body of the loop in `my_method()` should refer to each element's position, not to the array itself:

```
System.out.println(args[i]);
```

Comment: Maybe `paramStringArray` is `String[].class`.

Comment: I'm betting the code was not copied correctly, so it's hard to know what's the real problem

Comment: Well, I tried Object#toString() before posting this question. Thanks, for the suggestion though

Comment: Sorry, my bad in typing the code. I actually have it the way you mentioned. I will edit the question.

Comment: @user2033666 ok, if that was not the problem then look at the last part in the answer - you're printing the _array_ and not the _contents_ of the array, use this to fix it: `System.out.println(args[i]);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to print `args[i]` and not what you have.

Also the method should be called with a `new String[]` instead of `new Object[]`.

Comment: Oh!! that was a really silly typo I made.. I changed it to args[i] and it works great now. :)
Thanks so much for noticing that!